# Regarding AmazonClientException

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have to implement some error handling logic for DynamoDb errors. As said by AWS documentation, the errors are divided into client and server errors.

May be I am missing something in the object browser, but I don't understand how I will retrieve the "HttpStatusCode StatusCode" for the client errors (AmazonClientException) ?

This is just part of the server errors (AmazonServiceException) only.
As, I need to do some logging based on the error code, it seems that it can not be obtained from client exceptions currently.

Comment: What SDK are you using?

Comment: I had SDk version 1.5.2.2 and now updated to 1.5.3.0....but the exception classes are same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no status code for a `AmazonClientException` which is not also an `AmazonServiceException`.  If you have one from the service, it will be of the second type and you can get the status code.  If you have one of the first type, it could be because you don't have an internet connection, or the service responded with a malformed response (perhaps not even HTTP, who knows!).

It's a little confusing that they decided to extend `AmazonClientException` with `AmazonServiceException`, because it means that (in java) you might have to do something like this:

```
try {
    // ... make some dynamo requests ...
} catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
    // aha, I can get at the status code!
} catch (AmazonClientException e) {
    // OK, something really bizarre happened... perhaps dynamo is
    // down, or I'm having internet issues.
}
```

Comment: Yes, I see that exceptions e.g. when the access key is wrong are of Service type. I was hoping that this should be a client exception of some 4XX type as given at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ErrorHandling.html 

Even after disconnecting I see the error is Service exception, saying that could not resolve xyz hostname. I am not able to simulate a client exception yet.

I feel that the exception classes could have been designed or named better.

Also in .Net, I don't see any inheritance relation between these exceptions in object browser.